# php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Tags: magento, magento2

Why `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` command has destroied all my directories?

After `Magento\Deploy\Model\Mode->enableDeveloperMode()` it threw `Magento\Deploy\Model\Filesystem->cleanupFilesystem()`

Comment: you need to just run "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" command again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?